# HADOOP/PIG-LATIN:Counting the movies stars that worked together more often PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have to count the stars that worked together form IMDB small sample and then scale.

I have to use only for those actor in a movie and do not for a tv series

```
#Input: (actor, title, year, num, type, episode, billing, role)
raw = LOAD 'hdfs://cm:9000/uhadoop/shared/imdb/imdb-stars-example.tsv' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (actor, title, year, num, type, episode, billing, role);
#Line 1: Filter raw to make sure type equals 'THEATRICAL_MOVIE' 
 movies = FILTER raw BY type == 'THEATRICAL_MOVIE';
#Then I get the variables with stars and costars every billing that is equal to 1 is the movies star and every billing >=2 it is the co movie star
 c1 = FILTER movies BY billing == 1;
 c2 = FILTER movies BY billing >= 2;
 c3 = JOIN c1 BY title, c2 BY title;
```

From here I need to count the most frequent couple on the movies and my brain just juts down I have tried many things but always get an error.
Things like

```
actor_coactors_freq_movies = GROUP c3 BY actor;
actor_coactors_freq_movies_count = FOREACH actor_coactors_freq_movies GENERATE COUNT($1) AS count, 
group AS actor_pair;
ordered_actor_pair_count = ORDER actor_movie_count BY count DESC;
```

Obviously I am lost, I am a newbie in all this jazz.

Appreciate your help thanks

Answer (score 0):

Line 1: Filter raw to make sure type equals 'THEATRICAL_MOVIE'
movies = FILTER raw BY type == 'THEATRICAL_MOVIE';

-- Line 2: Generate new relation with full movie name (concatenating title+"-"+year+"-"+num) and actor
full_movies1 = FOREACH movies GENERATE CONCAT(title,'-',year,'-',num), actor;
full_movies2 = FOREACH movies GENERATE CONCAT(title,'-',year,'-',num), actor;

-- Line 3: Group the relation by actor
coactor_movies = JOIN full_movies1 BY $0, full_movies2 BY $0;
dump coactor_movies

coactor_movies2 = FOREACH coactor_movies GENERATE $0 as mv, $1 as act1, $3 as act2;
dump coactor_movies2

-- saco los pares con igual actor
coactor_movies3 = FILTER coactor_movies2 BY act1 != act2;
dump coactor_movies3

-- transformo los pares simetricos
coactor_movies4 = FOREACH coactor_movies3 GENERATE mv, FLATTEN((act1 < act2 ? (act1, act2) : (act2, act1)));
dump coactor_movies4

-- elimino ls duplicados
ca1 = DISTINCT coactor_movies4;
dump ca1

-- dejo solo los actores
ca2 = FOREACH ca1 GENERATE act1, act2;
dump ca2

actores = GROUP ca2 by (act1, act2);
results = FOREACH actores GENERATE FLATTEN(group) as (act1, act2), COUNT($1) as count;
or_results = ORDER results BY count DESC;